# Reseller club price detecting API

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Reseller club API for searching domains. Now suppose a domain is available and my customer go through Payment gateway to pay for it. How will I know what to charge for it? Is it a premium domain or a simple domain having price around $12?

The searching API does not tell me about domain price, just tells that domain is available or not.
Please comment if you have related info,